# Try open Word doc at my own network by VBA but it opens with macros disabled?

Tags: vba, security, ms-word

I have 1000' of Word docs where I need to

1. insert a Footer with fields for FILENAME, PAGE and NUMPAGE
2. update the fields in the Footer
3. save the doc again

I traverse the folder hieraki from a topfolder and it works nicely and handles me a doc-object (Dim doc as Word.Document) I have to process with 1)..3).

That's where the problems starts !

The code I plan to do the processing is:

```
Sub insertFooterIfMissing(file As String)
    Dim appWrd As New Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim footer As HeaderFooter
'    Set appWrd = CreateObject(Word.Application)
    ' Open the Word document
    Set doc = appWrd.Documents.Open(file)    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< (A)
    ' Check if the apppWrd footer exists
    'If doc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Exists Then
    If Len(doc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text) = 1 Then
        ' insert the Footer here AND update the Footer
        'Debug.Print "Nu indsættes Footer i : " & file
        With Selection
            .WholeStory
            ' Delete existing Footer - if any
            .Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
            ' Insert new fields in Footer
            .Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:= _
                "FILENAME  ", PreserveFormatting:=True
            ' move to the right margin and write "Side "
            .TypeText Text:=vbTab & vbTab & "Side "
            ' and insert the Page field
            .Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:= _
                "PAGE  ", PreserveFormatting:=True
            ' write " af "
            .TypeText Text:=" af "
            ' and insert NumPages field
            .Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:= _
                "NUMPAGES  ", PreserveFormatting:=True
            .Select
            .Fields.Update
        End With
    
    Else
        ' Just leave it be
    End If
    UpdateFieldsInFooter doc
    ' Save the documente with the new updated Footer-fields
    doc.Save
    ' Close the document
    doc.Close
    Set doc = Nothing
    Set appWrd = Nothing
End Sub

Sub UpdateFieldsInFooter(doc As Word.Document)
    Dim Scn As Section, HdFt As HeaderFooter
    'Update fields in footers
    With doc
      'Loop thru all Sections
      For Each Scn In .Sections
        'Loop thru all Footers in Section
        For Each HdFt In Scn.Footers
          With HdFt
            .Range.Fields.Update
          End With
        Next
      Next
    End With
End Sub
```

The line marked with (A) gives me a message saying the document is opened with macros disabled!

I can't figure out how I shall do my settings in "Center for security" in Word to prevent that disabling - Teach me!

Comment: Does it matter if macros are disabled in `doc`?  You're not trying to run any code *in* that file, only *on* it.  Try adding `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before opening, and that may disable the pop-up.

Comment: There IS a lot of code in the Normal.dotm the doc object is referencing and I want that code to be useable when I've done the Footer updating and saved the document again.
I think the problem is tha settings in the "Center for security ..." - I've had a lot of problems in the periode where MS implemented the shit - but I can't figure out what checkmarks to set or delete - it's driving me crazy !

Comment: I've now tried to insert

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

it does NOT kill that messagebox saying that the doc is opened with macros disabled :-(

Comment: Which settings in the Trust Center have you already tried changing? When replying to someone in a comment, tag there name like this @JohnM so we get notified of your reply.

Comment: In the trust center you can set files in specific locations (folders) as trusted, so macros will always load from files in this location. Of course you have to make sure that only trusted files can be saved to that location by trusted people.

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/51008-inserting-footer-if-doesnt-exist.html . For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: @JohnM, 
Last I have tried to make a trusted location - still macros are disbled
Earlier I have tried to manpulate the checkmarks according to my understanding - but I think some of the settings overrule other settings ... to me that dialog a a total mess and not for normal humans to understand !
I would think that allowing "files from my network" should be allowed to open with macros anabled - that dialog has been a problem since it was implemented !
I can't figure out how it should be handled :-(

Comment: You could try: 1. if you can move the 1000s of documents into a folder on your local device then do that ... run your code on them ... afterwards, move them back to the network location; 2. Trust Center > Macro Settings ... select (AT YOUR RISK, and remember to change back afterwards!) Enable All Macros (not recommended ...); 3. If you have one, sign your code (ie whatever file contains the code you posted, above) with a code signing cert; 4. try 1 and 2 and/or 3 together